# awk — getting minus instead of FILENAME

Tags: unix, awk

I am trying to add the filename to the end of each line as a new field. It works except instead of getting the filename I get `-`.

Base file:

```
070323111|Hudson
```

What I want:

```
070323111|Hudson|20150106.csv
```

What I get:

```
070323111|Hudson|-
```

This is my code:

```
mv $1 $1.bak
cat $1.bak | awk '{print $0 "|" FILENAME}' > $1
```

Comment: You don't need the semicolon and newline in the `awk` script (though they work).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`-` is the way to present the filename when there is not such info. Since your are doing `cat $1.bak | awk ...`, `awk` is not reading from a file but from stdin.

Instead, just do:

```
awk '...' file
```

in your case:

```
awk '{print $0 "|" FILENAME}' $1.bak > $1
```

From `man awk`:

> FILENAME
>
> The name of the current input file.  If no files are specified on the
>   command line, the value of FILENAME  is “-”.  However, FILENAME is
>   undefined inside the BEGIN rule (unless set by getline).

Comment: well, this was some kind of experiment I did... I have to fix it :) By the way, congrats for the 80K! Have 2x2 badges as a present! :)